# UTF-8 Encoding Going Wrong in Chrome Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, encoding, safari, webkit

I am seeing this problem.  In Chrome/Safari, Ajax response that gets set as content containing some special characters (ie, spanish tilde 'i') are not interpreted correctly.

This problem is perfectly summarized with an example here:

> I tried Firefox and IE and both works fine. Only Chrome is not
>   displaying web page correctly. This is the URL: http://maixner.eu/#bio
>   As you can see, some characters are wrong. This line: 2012 - Muzeum
>   modernÃ­ho umÄ›nÃ­, Olomouc, Czech Republic Should be: 2012 - Muzeum
>   moderního umění, Olomouc, Czech Republic
>
> Dev details: 1) There is index.html page with javascript file, which
>   loads data via AJAX (calls PHP file) 2) index.html file has
>   content-type set to UTF-8 3) all files are UTF-8 encoded 4) javascript
>   injects innerHTML using XMLHttpRequest class with responseText 5) php
>   file has header('Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8"');

And here:

> Have similar (or same) problem, but with spanish characters. 
>   I have set Apache to use UTF-8 
>   I have set php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
>   I have set html  
>   I have set html  
>   But Chorme (only Chrome, FF, IE, etc work ok) shows this:
>
> [Post headers] 
>   ... 
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 
>   ... 
>   [Some random post value from the form] 
>   ------WebKitFormBoundary0wi0NAscQiUkF2hJ 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="s_name" 
>   OxÃ­geno 100.4 FM BogotÃ¡ <-- characters are wrong! should read: Oxígeno 100.4 FM Bogotá

[Original Post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LVYMBC6LMm8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Basically, in my case, it's because of the request header sent by the browser.

chrome sends: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, **only**.
firefox sends: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Without the charset=UTF-8, the server defaults to ISO, and decodes its wrongly.

Comment: Yes, that ended up being the real issue.  Had to force `charset=UTF-8` for webkit browsers.

Comment: Where / how did you do the `charset=UTF-8` forcing?

Answer (score -1):

In the php header function you have an extra " before the closing of the string. It should be

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it.  I have a Java app that has the header set correctly and it is seeing the same problem.

Comment: @mtyson That is a problem in the example page (http://maixner.eu/#bio) Can you show the other page? or can you set up a simple example page?